# Переопределение функции в javascript (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, javascript, функции

Доброго времени суток!

Переопределить возвращаемое значение функции.
Допустим есть:

```
function getSettings() {
  return  { набор настроек}
}
```

вызывается в шаблоне для:

```
$('#text').editor(getSettings());
```

В определенных обстоятельствах мне нужно расширить набор возвращаемых настроек.
Т.е. хотелось бы иметь что-то типа:

```
//новая
function getSettings() {
  setting = getSettings(); //получаем старые настройки
  newsetting = { новые настройки};
  $.merge(setting ,newsetting );
  return  setting;
}
```

Я плохо знаком  javascript и JQuery, поэтому я здесь

Comment: Это уже рекурсия...

     //новая
     function getSettings() {
     setting = getSettings(); //получаем старые настройки
     newsetting = { новые настройки};
     $.merge(setting ,newsetting );
     return  setting;
     }

Answer (score 1):

*[$.merge](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/) "склеивает" два **списка**. Если настройки возвращаются в виде **объекта**, необходимо использовать [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)!*

---

Вариант с переопределением имени функции:

```
var oldGetSettings = getSettings; // без скобок

function getSettings() {
    var value = oldGetSettings();
    // other stuff
}
```

С другой стороны, вам можно просто сменить имя вызываемой функции в шаблоне:

```
$('#text').editor(mySexyFunction());
```

Или даже так, если новых настроек не очень много (чтобы не нарушить читабельность кода):

```
$('#text').editor($.extend(getSettings(), { // ну или $.merge
    new_setting: 1,
    another_setting: 2
}));
```

Comment: Вариант не работает. Видимо из-за этого "высасывания" http://shamansir.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes
В шаблоне этого просто, но я делаю плагин и придется менять полностью шаблон

Answer (score 0):

Если вы пишите плагин, то советую делать следующим образом ([Смотреть пример.](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/Dtavn/))

```
$.fn.editor = function(options){
   options = $.extend({
      param_1: 'default_val_1', // дефолтный параметр
      param_2: 'default_val_2'  // дефолтный параметр
   },options);
   /*
   функции плагина и т.д.
   */
}
// подключение плагина с новыми параметрами
$('#text').editor({
   param_1: 'some_val_1',
   param_2: 'some_val_2'
});
```